# I can't send emails on Ubuntu server [javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException]

Tags: java, linux, spring, email, ssl

I can't send emails on Unbuntu server suddenly.

It's happened since today.
It's still working on local.

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
nested exception is:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1907)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:666)
```

**JAVA:**
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)

**Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:**
SSL-Session:
Protocol  : TLSv1.3
Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384

Comment: Is this hosted on a VPS or corp VM? Could be the port is blocked

Comment: Confirm it by ssh into the VPS then either ssmtp or smtpc to test. If it also failed, try different email provider that use other port

Comment: AWS _does_ block SMTP by default.

Comment: @Martheen do I have to install ssmtp or smtpc? it has neither of them.

Comment: How could I unblock it? I didn't think it that way since it had been working until yesterday. @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-

Comment: I am using aws lightsail and I guess the port isn't blocked. @Martheen

Comment: Don't guess. Confirm. Pick either and you'll see whether the VPS or the provider block you

Comment: Thank you. It's not blocked. @Martheen

Comment: So you've used ssmtp/smtpc, and with the exact same parameters, running from the server, you can send emails?

Comment: @Martheen A blocked port wouldn't result in an error _"No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)"_. This error probably means that the server is using TLS v1.1 or earlier which are disabled by defaults since Java 11.0.11, and given that version was released recently, I'm going to guess it started failing when Java was upgraded.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like your server uses TLSv1.1 or earlier, and you recently upgraded your Java to version 11.0.11. This version of Java has disabled TLSv1.0 and TLSv1.1 by default, see for example the [Oracle Java 11.0.11 release notes](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/11-0-11-relnotes.html) (though AFAIK this applies to all OpenJDK-derived versions):

> security-libs/javax.net.ssl
> ➜ **Disable TLS 1.0 and 1.1**
>
> TLS 1.0 and 1.1 are versions of the TLS protocol that are no longer
> considered secure and have been superseded by more secure and modern
> versions (TLS 1.2 and 1.3).
>
> These versions have now been disabled by default. If you encounter
> issues, you can, at your own risk, re-enable the versions by removing
> "TLSv1" and/or "TLSv1.1" from the `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms`
> security property in the `java.security` configuration file.

I suggest that you try if removing `TLSv1.1` from the `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` property in the `java.security` file fixes your problem, and if that fails, to try removing `TLSv1`. This would be an indication that your mailserver needs to be updated or configured to support more recent and more secure versions of TLS.

Comment: I got the same issue with gmail. Where do I find the configuration file in Intellij?

Comment: @AlGrant You need to modify the configuration file of the Java installation used to run your project. If you're running from within IntelliJ, go to your Project Structure, and under Project check which JDK you're using, and then click Edit to see its installation path. For Java 8, it is usually in `jre/lib/security`, for Java 9 in `lib/security` inside that installation path. If you run your program outside IntelliJ then you need to modify the Java installation that's on the `PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have ubuntu OS then go to

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security
```

then find `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms`

Then remove `TLSv1, TLSv1.1`

reboot the server and try to send mail again.